# apt-get -f install removed software center and several other files

Tags: software-installation

I ran `sudo apt-get -f install` and several files and programs were removed including software center. Is there a way to re-download everything as if ubuntu was new again without a cd? This computer does not have a cd-rom drive. I'd be fine with losing all the data on this computer.

Also, when I run `sudo apt-get install` (almost anything) I get errors about dependencies and files not being available.

Thanks to anyone who can help.

Comment: For clarification, please edit your question to show the output of *uname -a* from the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From command line, run:
*sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade*

Should resolve your dependency issues.

**Amended**
If it doesn't, you could try:
*sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -f dist-upgrade*

OR

*sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -f upgrade*

Similar to above listed, but with -f option added, obviously.

If the above options do not help you, you could run:

*sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -f install ubuntu-desktop*
(Or replace ubuntu-desktop with whatever version you're using, your question doesn't specify)

Comment: I tried that just now, after it ran it came up that there were some dependencies not met. I'm also still getting the same errors.

Comment: You're welcome. If this resolved your issue, please approve the answer, so other users with the same problem can see this as a [SOLVED] question.